# How to know using deserialized object if any particular node in xml exists

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am under a situation in `silverlight` (c#) where
  The situation is that : I have deserialized  xml in to c# class object. and now i want to know using my c# code (using object created on deserialization)
  that if there is "`disableothers`" exists in my xml or not. If it does then i have to call any function.

To achieve this i deserilized the xml succesfully and my object of "`parameter`" class(root) is "`parameter`".

```
//I mean something like this
//Remember that "parameter" is the object obtained on succesful deserializing root class of xml.
if (parameter.Parameter.Component.Attributes.DisableOthers == exists in xml) 
{
    CallToAnyFunctionToDoSomeThing();
}
```

NOTE: I am sorry if do mistake in naming "disableothers" (because i am calling it "node" in subject of question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but if you can check it like this :

```
var disableOthers = parameter.Parameter.Component.Attributes.DisableOthers;
if (disableOther ! = null && disableOthers.Any()) 
{
    CallToAnyFunctionToDoSomeThing();
}
```

Comment: What is this Any() do here ?

Comment: Any() method will return true if the given sequence contains any elements in that and false otherwise. So it is required to check if your list is not null and it contains elements. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that this works:

```
if (parameter.Parameter.Component.Attributes.DisableOthers != null && parameter.Parameter.Component.Attributes.DisableOthers.Length > 0) 
{
    CallToAnyFunctionToDoSomeThing();
}
```

If DispableOthers is a dynamic list it should be Count rather than Length.

Comment: Ok let me implement but ii am not abllet oundestand about length . please xplain i deeply

Comment: Ok let me implement but i am not able to undestand about length .Could you please explain a bit more why do we use length here ?

Comment: DisableOthers is a collection, depending on how an empty collection is shown in the xml it could be null or empty (Length or Count == 0)

Comment: @Caperah Ok. Could you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077785/how-to-implement-disable-functionality-in-redering-gui-by-an-object-obtained-on (IT IS STILL UN-answered)